# How to release buffers in Web Audio Api?

Tags: html, webkit, web-audio-api

I love the Web Audio Api. The possibilities are fantastic. That being said its still in early stages. An what worries me most is that I have no idea how to release buffers / sounds that I no longer need. Sound buffers with always new sontent since I will be mixing live sound from musicians / DJs / moderators connected via websockets.

The following code simulates load an playback of new buffers in a row. I need web audio api to add effects mixing and so everybody can hear live result with his performance.

Unfortunately, this code eats whole ram and crashes both mobile and desktop safari. I have no idea how to release those large buffers once they were played, and I no longer need them. I really need to load new large data in their place in memory. Have anyone idea? Otherwise I am stuck with first 8 files played not able to load any more.

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var total=0;

function onTouchStart(){
    setInterval(function(){
    total+=10;
    source = context.createBufferSource();    
    source.connect(context.destination); // simulates loading large file
    source.buffer=context.createBuffer(1, 10*1024*1024, context.sampleRate);
    source.noteOn(0);
    source.noteOff(0); // acording to w3c spec resources should be deleted immediately.
    // making source property and call delete or =null will release nether source or buffer i am desperate.
    console.log(total,'mb'); //
    },1000);
}

document.addEventListener( "touchstart", onTouchStart );
document.addEventListener( "click", onTouchStart );
```

Answer (score 2):

Memory management in JavaScript uses garbage collection which makes the term "immediately" relative. The buffers won't really be released until webkit thinks it's time to do so. You can see this on action by doing a timeline recording in the Chrome Developer Tools (not sure if there's any way to do so in Safari, though). Check this article on how to do that: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline

Also, since you're attaching the event listener to the document you will start another round of intervals for each time you tap the device, so if you'd happen to touch it twice you'll be creating the double amount of buffers, which means 20mb per second.

Having said that, have you tried this while actually playing real files? You probably won't have this issue since the garbage collector will be able to keep up while the files are playing. 10mb big mp3's or ogg's are minutes worth of audio.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, the lifetime of your objects is critical - particularly the "source" object, and its .buffer.  If it's tightly constrained, Javascript GC should be cleaning up for you.  In real-world, not sure you'd be quickly using/releasing so many 10Mb buffers?

Comment: well the problem is i will be mixing realtime audio data from multiple musicians / human speakers live via websockets. so yes i need to be able to release old big data that is not needed anymore and fast since memory in ipad2 for example fits only 8x10m files and than i am stuck with them with no way to get rid of them to load new ones. i am desperate :(